# How to show that this binomial sum satisfies the Fibonacci relation?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

> The binomial sum
>   $$s_n=\binom{n+1}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots$$
>   satisfies the Fibonacci relation.

I failed to prove that $\binom{n-k+1}{k}=\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k}$... Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Write their formulas....

Comment: @N.S. But it's messy for me... Are there any combinatorial proofs?

Comment: It is actually very easy, if you have the right formula, which is: $\binom{n-k+1}{k+1}=\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k+1}$..The proof is two lines long.... The formula you posted is wrong, that's why you failed ...

Comment: For intuition, consider Pascal's triangle. Each binomial coefficient in the triangle is in exactly one of your $s_n$s, and every term that is in $s_n$ arises as the sum of a term from $s_{n-1}$ and a term from $s_{n-2}$, and this uses each term of $s_{n-1}$ and $s_{n-2}$ exactly once.

Comment: @N.S. Well...$s_n=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n-k+1}{k}$ Is it wrong? Why $\binom{n-k+1}{k+1}$?

Comment: A combinatorial proof based on number of tiling of $n\times1$ board by squares and dominos is given in Benjamin, Quinn: Proofs that Really Count; Identity 4, [p.4](http://books.google.com/books?id=FXLGzXwbwIAC&pg=PA4).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I was going to give the same suggestion :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the words of length $n+1$ with letters 0,1 and no two consecutive 1s.

Prove that they are counted by the Fibonacci numbers.

Now count the same kind of words that contain exactly $k$ letters 1.

Answer (score 15):

This approach was explained in the above comments by [N.S](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation#comment193327_81805) and 
and
[Henning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation#comment193360_81805)

---

We can show $$\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k=F_{n+1}$$
by induction.

Note that I did not specify the range for $k$. I am using the usual convention that $\binom pq$ is considered zero whenever $q<0$ or $q>p$. **EDIT:** After reading Marc van Leeuwen's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation/169927#169927) I've realized, that this is true for non-negative $q$ only, so I've change range to $k\ge0$.

$1^\circ$ We can verify $n=-1,0,1,2$ by hand.

$2^\circ$ Inductive step: Suppose $n>1$. We want to show that this is true for $n+1$ and assume validity of the formula for $0,1,\dots,n$.

$$\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n+1-k}k=\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}{k-1}=
\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-1-(k-1)}{k-1}=
\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{j\ge0} \binom{n-1-j}{j}= F_{n+1}+F_n = F_{n+2}.$$

---

This proof can be visualized as follows: We are computing the sums of terms in Pascal triangle along diagonals.

It suffices to notice that each element on $k$-th diagonal is a sum of an element from $(k-1)$-th diagonal and $(k-2)$-th diagonal.

(I've taken the picture from [thesis](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/papers/bakal/Stupakova.pdf) of my student I supervised some time ago.
I am not sure whether she made the picture herself or found it somewhere on the Internet.)

[image: PascalFib]

Answer (score 6):

We begin with the identity:
$$
\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}.
$$
We apply the identity to 
$$
s_n=\binom{n+1}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots
$$
to get
$$
s_n= \underbrace{\color{blue}{\binom{n}{0}} + \color{grey}{\binom{n}{-1}}}_{\text{first term}} + \underbrace{\color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{1}} + \color{brown}{\binom{n-1}{0}}}_{2\text{nd term}} +
\underbrace{\color{blue}{\binom{n-2}{2}} + \color{brown}{\binom{n-2}{1}} }_{3\text{rd term}} + \cdots 
$$

Notice that the terms in are $\color{blue}{s_{n-1}}$ and those in brown/red $\color{brown}{s_{n-2}}$. (I had to work out what $s_{n-1}$ and $s_{n-2}$ was in order to catch the pattern, in case you're wondering how I knew). And so we have our fibonacci relation
$$
s_n = \color{blue}{s_{n-1}} + \color{brown}{s_{n-2}}
$$

As for the $\binom{n}{-1}$ term, just define it to be $0$...If that's not allowed, then wave your hands and mumble something.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with proving $\binom{n-k+1}k=\binom{n-k}k+\binom{n-k-1}k$ is that it is not true (try $k=0$ for starters). However for $n\geq1$ one has
$$\begin{aligned}
  s_{n-1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}\binom{n-k}k\\
 &= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}(\binom{n-1-k}k+\binom{n-1-k}{k-1})\\
 &= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac {n-1}2\rfloor}\binom{n-1-k}k
     +\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}\binom{n-1-k}{k-1}\\
 &= s_{n-2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor-1}\binom{n-2-k}k\\
 &= s_{n-2}+s_{n-3},\\
 \end{aligned}
$$
so that the sequence $(s_n)_{n\geq-1}$ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence (with $s_{-1}=\binom00=1$ by the same definition as $s_n$ for $n\in\mathbf N$). Since moreover $s_{-1}=s_0=1$ one has $s_n=F_{n+2}$ for all $n\geq-1$.

One wonders what is the point of starting the defining expression for $s_n$ with $\binom{n+1}0$, as the "$+1$" only increases the shift with respect to the Fibonacci sequence. To resume, one has
$$ F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}\binom{n-1-k}k
  \qquad\text{for }n\geq1.
$$

Added: although the summation runs into terms $0$ once $k>n/2$ (this is implicitly used in the argument above where we dropped the final term from the first summation in the third line), it should *not* be written as an unbounded (therefore infinite) summation: when one gets to terms for $k>n$, the terms are again nonzero, by the usual convention for binomial coefficients with negative upper index. This point should have been made clearer in the question.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}\color{#66f}{\large s_{n}}&
={n+1 \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + {n - 1 \choose 2} + \cdots
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{n + 1 - k \choose k}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\ \overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \varphi^{+}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1 - k} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\ds{=\ \dsc{n + 1 - k \choose k}}}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\varphi \equiv {1 + \root{5} \over 2}}$ is the
>   [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio).
>   Then,

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large s_{n}}&
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \varphi^{+}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z}
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{1 \over z\pars{1 + z}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \varphi^{+}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z}
{1 \over 1 - 1/\bracks{z\pars{1 + z}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \varphi^{+}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 2} \over z^{2} + z - 1}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \varphi^{+}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 2} \over \pars{z + \varphi}\pars{z - \varphi^{-1}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
={\pars{1 - \varphi}^{n + 2} \over -\varphi - \varphi^{-1}}
+{\pars{1 + \varphi^{-1}}^{n + 2} \over \varphi^{-1} + \varphi}
\end{align}

> However,
>   $\ds{\quad\varphi + \varphi^{-1}=\root{5}\,,\quad 1 + \varphi^{-1}=\varphi\quad}$ such that

$$
\color{#66f}{\large s_{n}}
={\varphi^{n + 2} - \pars{1 - \varphi}^{n + 2} \over \root{5}}
=\color{#66f}{\large F_{n + 2}}
$$

> where $\ds{F_{m}}$ is a
>   [Fibonacci Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).