# Fibonacci sequence, strings without 00, and binomial coefficient sums

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Refer to the sequence $S$ where $S_n$ denotes the number of n-bit strings that do not contain the pattern 00.
By considering the number of n-bit strings with exactly i 0's, show that

$\displaystyle f_{n+2} = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \binom{n+1 - i}{i}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$
where $f$ denotes the Fibonacci sequence.

So I know the Fibonacci sequence consists of $0, 1, 1, 2, 3,\dots$
And $S_n=f_{n+2}$.  But what else?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: By $C$ do you mean binomial coefficient?

Comment: I've formatted your question with $\LaTeX$, it'll be applied when someone will approve it.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as this one (or at least very similar): [How to show that this binomial sum satisfies the Fibonacci relation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation). Only one answer there, perhaps it would deserve adding something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many strings of length $n$ which do not contain "00" and contains precisely $i$ zeroes are there?

Notice that any zero must be followed by 1 or be at the and. For the sake of simplicity, let us consider string of length $n+1$ which is obtained by adding 1 to the original string.

So no we are counting the strings of length $n+1$ which are obtained from $i$ strings of the form "01" with 1's on the remaining position.

If we regard the whole string "01" as one character, then there are only $n+1-i$ positions and we have to place this "combined character" on $i$ of them. So we have $\binom{n+1-i}i$ positions.

---

BTW this can be regarded as a more detailed solution based on the hint from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation/81827#81827).