# Showing that this sum is equal to the fibonacci numbers

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

How do I show that the following sum is equal to the fibonacci numbers? Atleast numerical evaluation suggests it is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\binom{n+1-k}{n+1-2k}
$$
The image below shows how it moves through pascals triangle, it starts at the right $1$ on line $n+1$, if the upper line is $n=0$.
[image]

Comment: Use induction, showing that your formula satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence relation $F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$.

Comment: @Bob1123 right, that was pretty obvious. Oh well

Comment: It may be easy to show that the relation is true, but it does not make the identity obvious. Take a look at the last picture [here](http://trianglepascal.com/pascals-triangle-fibonacci-numbers/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that:
$$ \binom{n+1-k}{n+1-2k}=\binom{n+1-k}{k} $$
and there is a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169927/204937)