# I want to find the closed form of $\sum\limits _{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n-i \choose i}$

Tags: combinatorics

I can't find the starting points.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Try to compute the first terms of your sequence, and then make a conjecture.

Comment: The starting points are $f(0)={0 \choose 0}=1$ and $f(1)={1 \choose 0}=1$

Comment: Is it the Fibonacci  Numbers?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: *I want to find the closed form of* $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n-i\choose i}$ - And I want to drive a Rolls Royce, for instance. :-$)$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: yes they are.

Comment: Sorry, @JackD'Aurizio, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Prove by induction that:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{2n-i}{i}=F_{2n+1} $$
or just look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation), then adjust your formula to cover the remaining cases.