# Fibonacci sequence in a double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n-j \choose j}{n-k \choose k}=x$$

Setting $n:=1,2,3,4,5$ we find that $x:=1,1,4,9,25$

It looks like $\sqrt{x}:=1,1,2,3,5$ is the sequence of Fibonacci number.

I can't show that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n-j \choose j}{n-k \choose k}=F_n^2$$

Where $F_n$ is the [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Am I correct that this double sum produces the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: That follows directly from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation, by squaring the identity $\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k=F_{n+1}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show that this binomial sum satisfies the Fibonacci relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81805/how-to-show-that-this-binomial-sum-satisfies-the-fibonacci-relation)