# Fibonacci numbers written as sums of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

So I came across this formula of Fibonacci numbers as a binomial sum [1] [2]

$$ F_n = \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{\lfloor {\frac {n - 1} 2} \rfloor} \dbinom {n - k - 1} k $$

I'm not really sure that this formula actually valid, I've computed some of the first terms and they don't look very much like Fibonacci numbers to me.

Maybe the identity is wrong, but several places have it stated in the same way.
Does anyone know more about this identity? Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from math import factorial, floor

def c(n,k):
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))

def f(n):
    s=0
    for k in range(floor((n-1)/2)):
        s += int(c(n-k-1,k))
    return s

for n in range(1,6):
    # computing F(n)
    print(f(n))
```

And the output is

```
0
0
1
1
4
```

[1] https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fibonacci_Number_as_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients

[2] https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169893/68328

Comment: @MatthewDaly not really a duplicate. In the post you mentioned they're discussing more interesting things, but here I've actually computed the first terms of this sum, and they don't really look like fibonacci numbers to me.. it's a different question (probably more related to an incorrect formula than something else)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? If it's 3, using `//` instead of `/` obviates the need for `floor`, `int`. If it's 2 (which will be deprecated in January 2020), `/` does the same job as `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a programming problem. In python, the loop

```
for k in range(n):
```

will execute its statements inside for $k=0,1,...,n-1$, so that the computed sums contain one term less than necessary.

Comment: Ah, thanks, it seems like I messed up that range..

Comment: @average For more information on them, [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).